# Wrapping angular typeAhead in separate directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

My goal was to wrap angular-ui typeAhead directive into easily re-usable component, that could be used like this:

```
<input my-person-lookup="myModel.personId" ></input>
```

I've achieve this by writing my custom directive, and specifying static template for typeahead. Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O0lWHjtLPHssbw9Q52cD?p=preview)

Now, I would like to build this template dynamically, and then compile it:

```
  var html = '<input type="text" ng-model="directiveModel.selectedPerson" typeahead=" p as p.name for p in people" typeahead-min-length="1" typeahead-wait-ms="200" typeahead-editable="false" placeholder="type p"></input>';
  element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
```

Unfortunately this approach didn't work [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ojGB8XqIseZgbYQFVxMe?p=preview).

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move your data to the wrapping controller and remove your isolated scope.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I91ET7GfXRlPkyfeNKcV?p=preview)

[Plunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/FoeVfTdBAIC2yuY12zxZ?p=preview)

Comment: I was terrified by a number of unnecessary JS dependencies (jQuery, Bootstrap's CSS, angular-ui) so cleaned up the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/YK7okuZlSoiglmGhtq5s?p=preview

Comment: Wait... so by putting data (service) to wrapping controller, I create a hard dependency between controller and directive - which I don't want. I want directive to work completely independent from parameters / services defined in parent controller.

Edit: Also, since this directive will be re-used between many different applications, I believe it is not a good idea to remove isolated scope.

Comment: You could give the directive its own controller and scope, and pass in the wrapping controller if needed. I added a second plunker to demo.

Comment: Aha! Specifying explicit controller for the directive is the right way to go. I was trying to use directive declaration function as its controller, which didn't work. Thanks a lot!